# setState not updating state even with callback and handleFunction - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a handle function which is called in another component. This passess a value called data, which I want to update into my `state`.

```
//basic code
initialState = {
  wordCount:"Some Value"
  text: "Some value"
}
class Home extends Component{
  state = initialState;
  handler(data){
    console.log('Arrived',data)
    this.setState({wordCount:data,text:GetText(data,this.state)});
    this.validation();
  }
  validation(){
    console.log(this.state.wordCount)
  }
  render(){
  return (
      <div><Component handlerFunc={this.handler.bind(this)}</div>
  )
  }
```

Printing out `data` in my handler function I do receive the right information as a string. The I use setState to replace `wordCount`'s initial value with `data`. I do the same with `text`. *GetText* returns a string.

But when validation is run, my state is exactly the same. How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Note: **setState** in react is asynchronous.

This means there is no guarantee that state will have changed by the next statement. What you can do to avoid this is setState accepts callback which will be called when set state finishes.

```
this.setState(
   {
       wordCount:data,
       text:GetText(data,this.state)
   }, 
   () => { 
    // Gets called when setState updates the state
    this.validation() 
});
```

Comment: Ok. But validate is no longer being called (validate function just console.logs `this.state.wordCount` . I see no output because I changed this. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @BuddyBob You may have problem with the use of ```this```. Try accessing state inside the callback or use console log. You will see that the state will definitely have changed

Comment: I have never messed with `this`. How could it be incorrect. Also, in my callback I am running validation. Which has a console.log(). It seems that it is never being run in the first place.

Comment: @BuddyBob Is the `Arrived` being printed in console form above example? Then you will get console.log() in the code. If there is nothing then you might have encountered error in ```GetText(data,this.state)``` that function. Try using error handlers and see if there are any errors

Comment: Crazy right. I call GetText seperatly, works fine when I console.log it. Arrived is also logged. My Brain hurts lmao.

Comment: How about you keep debugger inside the setState callback and outside. So you exactly see what is happening @BuddyBob